# Alpine x-transition doesn't work inside jinja2 template for loop

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, fastapi, alpine.js

Inside this code, I can get the two divs to toggle when showOriginal is toggled, but the animation simply doesn't work? In this case, summaries are sqlmodel objects rendered by Jinja2.

```
 {% for summary in summaries %}
    <div x-data="{showOriginal: true }" class=" flex flex-row">
        <div class="ml-4 py-2">
            <div>
                <p @click="showOriginal = !showOriginal" class="text-xs"><span x-show="showOriginal">Show
                        Original</span><span x-show="!showOriginal">Show
                        Summarised</span>
                </p>
                <div x-show="showOriginal" x-transition.delay.1000ms>
                    {{summary.title}} </div>
                <div x-show="!showOriginal" x-transition.delay.1000ms>
                    {{summary.paper.title}}</div>
            </div>
            <a href={{ url_for('summary', summary_id=summary.id) }} class=" md:text-lg text-baseline text-underline">
            </a>

            <p class="text-sm text-green-300">{{ summary.paper.authors[0].name }},
                {{summary.paper.authors[-1].name}} et
                al.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

How I implement the js in base.html, which the above template inhertits from.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.7.0/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.8.4"
        integrity="sha384-wg5Y/JwF7VxGk4zLsJEcAojRtlVp1FKKdGy1qN+OMtdq72WRvX/EdRdqg/LOhYeV"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% if DEBUG %} {{ hot_reload.script(url_for('hot-reload')) | safe }}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
    <link href={{url_for('static', path='/dist/output.css' )}} rel="stylesheet" />

    <title>Openpaper.science </title>
</head>
```

Comment: can you also add the code where you are loading js libs and initiizing alpine.js

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the toggling elements in the devtools. Are Alpine.js transition classes being applied?

If not, it may be because you don't have the `defer` attribute on your Alpine.js script import.

Should be:

```
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.7.0/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

If the transition classes are being applied and you're just not getting the desired effect with your choice of transition attributes, you may want to customize the classes and/or style the default transition classes differently.

https://alpinejs.dev/directives/transition#applying-css-classes